# Pre-Algebra Fractional Exponent Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

Why does $t^{\frac{3}{2}} \cdot t^{\frac{1}{2}} = t^2$?

What I tried to do was multiply the exponents together $\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$ so my final answer was $t^{\frac{3}{4}}$ but according to my Wileyplus homework it is $t^2$.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Remember the rule: $\;a^x\cdot a^y=a^{x+y}\;$. Product of two exponentials **with the same basis** gives the same basis with the powers summed.

Comment: Right. So it's 3/2 + 1/2 = 4/2 = 2. Thanks.

Comment: Don't you remember $t^a\times t^b=t^{a+b}$ ? May be using the logarithms could be easier $\log(t^a\times t^b)=\log(t^a)+\log(t^b)=a\times \log(t)+b\times \log(t)=(a+b)\log(t)=\log(t^{a+b})$

Comment: Try some values for t and see what happens

Answer (score 2):

When multiplying two of the same number raised to exponents (such as ${x^\frac{3}{2}}$ times $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$) you *add* the exponents.

$$x^a \cdot x^b = x^{a+b}$$

Only when raising a number to an exponent, and raising the result to an exponent do you multiply exponents together.

$$(x^a)^b = x^{a\cdot b}$$

Note:  $(x^{a})^{b} \neq x^{(a^b)}$

Answer (score 0):

Just remember this:
$$a^b+a^c= a^{b+c}$$
so in your problem,
$$a=t, \, b=3/2, \, c=1/2$$
and $$ t^3/2+t^1/2= t^{1/2+3/2}= t^4/2=t^2$$

hope this helped!